# Парсинг строк при чтении больших файлов c++

Tags: c++

В процессе поиска наиболее быстрого алгоритма чтения файла и парсинга данных, возникла ошибка.
Первоначально тип читаемых строк в файле (а именно интерес представляет последнее число типа float, а остальное мусор):
12242BENZ    H6   24  11.060   8.703   4.112

Поскольку, к примеру на хабре представлены разные методы [работы с iostream](https://habr.com/post/246257/), в силу моей низкой квалификации в c++ я решил не заморачиваться по поводу использования Boost::Spirit::Qi (хотя, если есть умельцы, которые могут подсказать путь для создания через Boost::Spirit::Qi парсера для float, то буду признателен) и использовать довольно простенький алгоритм:

```
ifstream fid("Benzene_Simu1_0_35ns.gro");
if (!fid) throw exception("Bad opening");   

std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

char buffer[80];
char * test;

//vector <float> coordinates(3);
float coordinates = 0.0;
vector <float> coordinate;

while (true)
{
    if (fid.eof()) break;

    fid.ignore(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(), '\n');
    fid.ignore(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(), '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
        fid.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        test = strrchr(buffer, ' '); //take pointer on last float in string
        std::advance(test, 1);
        sscanf(test, "%f", &coordinates); //select z_axis value
        coordinate.push_back(coordinates);
    }
    fid.ignore(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(), '\n');
}
cout << coordinate[sizeof(coordinate) - 1] << endl;
cout << clock()/1000 << endl;
_getch();
```

Так вот, в результате работы такого алгоритма в строке кода

```
sscanf(test, "%f", &coordinates); //select z_axis value
```

появляется ошибка

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5B031BCC (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001. occurred
```

Какие комментарии и замечания будут по поводу данной ситуации и кода?

Comment: Откуда взялась константа 120?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо всего прочего у вас куча игнорирования строк (т.е. их чтения в никуда) + неверная проверка конца файла. Так что вопрос - вы точно читаете строки?

Вы же не проверяете, что строка считана... Может, там какая-то ерунда, в буфере?

И, кстати, ваш `advance(test,1)` совершенно ни к чему. В отличие от проверки, не равен ли `test == nullptr`...

Comment: Игнорируются строки, которые совершенно не нужны, если есть возможность их пропуска другим способом, то подскажите как.
 Почему проверка конца неверная? Как сделать проверку что строка считана? И что за проверка test == nullptr?
Если не сложно, прокомментируйте пожалуйста

Comment: @DenisDanilov Кек. Нормальный комментарий? имеется в виду проверка указателя на то, что он nullptr, то есть нулевой.  (оператор сравнения `==` сравнивает левый операнд с правым и возвращает `true` когда операнды равны или `false` когда операнд не равны, если упрощенно)Или как раньше ещё писали test == NULL. Строка `test = strrchr(buffer, ' ');` может записть в test nullptr. И тогда вызов sscanf, вероятно, приведёт к ошибке (падению программы).

Comment: Да.Я уже понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если пробел не найден, то `strrchr(buffer, ' ');` возвратит нулевой указатель. Соответственно надо 1) проверять что у вас строка прочиталась, 2) проверять что пробел найден.